# Selecting the first <li> in a navigation bar

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the first `<li>` element of a my page's navigation bar so that I can make it half the size of the other items in the navigation bar.

Here is my CSS:

```
.nav{
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.nav li{ display:inline; }

.nav li:first-of-type { width: 50px; }

.nav li a {
    width: 118px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 8px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color:#666666;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li a:hover { background-color:#555555; }

.nav li.selected a { background-color: #FF731E; }
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="page01.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page02.html">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page03.html">Page3</a></li>
        <li><a href="page04.html">Page4</a></li>
        <li><a href="page05.html">Page5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried various things, including `:first-child` and `:first-of-type` but I can't seem to select the first item (which will be a home icon).

Nothing even managed to affect the page, unless I used `.nav li a:first-of-type` which made all the items 50px which was not my intended result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS styles the width on the anchor, so changing the width of the li is fairly fruitless. You really want to select the anchor under the first li, like:

```
.nav li:first-child a {
  width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use `.nav > li:first-child` (`first-child` has [**better browser support**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild) than the solutions in other answers).

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu3vb/2/)

Or if you just wanted to target the anchor inside of it, use `.nav > li:first-child > a`.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu3vb/3/)

---

**Side note:** You can leave out the direct child selector (`>`) if you want, I just tend to use it when possible as I assume it's slightly faster (not that it's noticeable).

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.nav li:nth-child(1){your style here}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav li:first-of-type a { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

To select only the first li item use this:

```
li:nth-child(1) {
    //Your style here 
}
```

If you want all the other childs to be styled other then the first you can also do this:

```
li:nth-child(n+2) {
    color: green;   
}
```

For styling only the last child do it like:

```
li:last-child {
    //Your style here
}
```

More about it here: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 1):

The first one, as Zenith said, is the best option because of browser support.

```
.nav li:first-child a{}

.nav li:nth-child(1) a{}

.nav li:first-of-type a{}

.nav li:nth-of-type(1) a{}
```